# HalvingGridSearchCV giving non-optimal results with min_resources='exhaust'

Tags: gridsearchcv

I am using `HalvingGridSearchCV` with 160 combinations and 1050 samples. When I use `min_resources` with `'exhaust'`, I get 6 iterations with the last iteration including 5 candidates and 640 samples. The process starts with 20 samples.

When I set `min_resources=30`, I also get 6 iterations with the last iteration having 5 candidates, but with 960 samples.

My understanding is that by using `'exhaust'`, the algorithm should figure out that 30 is a better value for `min_resources`. Instead it sets it to 20.

My ideal case would be for the last iteration to use all 1050 samples with the 5 candidates but I see no way to set parameters to make this happen.

My question is whether there is a bug in the `min_resources=exhaust` parameter value.